# How should i represent my features?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian, text-mining, natural-language

I use multinomial naive bayes to classify questions.
When I use tf-idfs for the words in each sentence as features, I get an accuracy of 67%.

I am trying to follow this paper: [Learning Question Classifiers*, Xin Li Dan Roth](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/acl/C/C02/C02-1150.pdf)

It seems like when they use both words and positional tags as features they achieve higher accuracy. So I tried adding the positional tags to my array of words, and generating tf-idfs for everything, and contrary to my beliefs my accuracy decreased - 65%.

Did I do something conceptually wrong here? Should I not represent the tags this way or is generating tf-idfs for them the wrong thing to do? I mean shouldn't I be getting a higher accuracy?

How would one go about doing this?

P.S. this is the dataset I use: [dataset](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/Data/QA/QC/)

I train on the 5500 questions.